# Tex Live does not show section title

Tags: pdftex, texlive, ubuntu

Here is a very simple latex example I copied online.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% For the equation* environment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
\begin{document}
\section{First example}

The well-known Pythagorean theorem \(x^2 + y^2 = z^2\) was proved to be invalid for other exponents, meaning the next equation has no integer solutions for \(n>2\):

\[ x^n + y^n = z^n \]

\section{Second example}

This is a simple math expression \(\sqrt{x^2+1}\) inside text.
And this is also the same:
\begin{math}
\sqrt{x^2+1}
\end{math}
but by using another command.

This is a simple math expression without numbering
\[\sqrt{x^2+1}\]
separated from text.

This is also the same:
\begin{displaymath}
\sqrt{x^2+1}
\end{displaymath}

\ldots and this:
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{x^2+1}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

After compiling with Tex Live, I get the following:[image: screenshot]. The section names are all gone. What is wrong with my Tex Live? I compiled with the command "latex file.tex" on Ubuntu 22.04. The command line output was --

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
> restricted \write18 enabled.
> entering extended mode
> (./notes.tex
> LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
> L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
> Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
> For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
> (./notes.aux) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Cmh.png) (./notes.aux) )
> Output written on notes.dvi (1 page, 1508 bytes).
> Transcript written on notes.log.

Comment: Compile with pdflatex to get a PDF.

Comment: Your TeX Live is not up-to-date (the current version is 2023). However, with TeX Live 2022 and using `pdflatex` I get a PDF with this output: https://i.imgur.com/WkxqgPp.png with `latex` I get a DVI with the same output. If you convert the DVI to PDF the fonts should be embedded while this additional step(s). If not, it could happen that the PDF viewer is not able to show some text. But you should not wast time with this. As Ulrike told: Use `pdflatex` (or `lualatex`) to directly generate a PDF.

Comment: Ah that does it. Thank you.